# InfluxDB influx-enterprise.key.json no such file or directory

Tags: influxdb

I try to install InfluxDB Enterprise Edition using this documentation: https://docs.influxdata.com/enterprise/v1.2/production_installation/. The Requirements suggest to either use a `license-key` or `license-path`, where I do it with the License Key.

In Step 2, after installing, configuring and starting the Data Nodes I try to [join the data nodes to the cluster](https://docs.influxdata.com/enterprise/v1.2/production_installation/data_node_installation/#join-the-data-nodes-to-the-cluster). But executing `influxd-ctl add-data enterprise-data-01:8088` gives me the error:

```
add-data: operation exited with error: open /tmp/influx-enterprise.key.json: no such file or directory
```

although I configured not to use the license-key json but rather the license-key.
I also have the json file, so I tried it with the `license-path` but still getting the same error. Has somebody else encountered the same issues?

**EDIT**
Issue has been resolved, I had to restart the Data nodes after I changed the configuration to use the `license-path` *facepalm*. I went into this problem as I previously entered an old license key.